# PHP Access same class from a file included inside the class

Tags: php, oop, class

Here is the class:

*functions.php*

```
class buildPage {

    public function Set($var,$val){
        $this->set->$var = $val;
    }

    function Body(){
        ob_start();

        include('pages/'.$this->set->pageFile);
        $page = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        return $page;
    }

    function Out(){
        echo $this->Body();
    }
}
```

So here is the main (index) page of the script.

*index.php*

```
include_once('include/functions.php');

$page = new buildPage();

$page->Set('pageTitle','Old Title');    
$page->Set('pageFile','about.php');

$page->Out();
```

Now as you can see, it includes about.php file through class, actually inside the class.

And now, I want to access the same buildPage() class to change the page title.

*about.php*

```
<?php

$this->Set('pageTitle','New Title');
echo '<h1>About Us</h1>';

?>
```

But unfortunately, nothing happens.

Please be kind to take few minutes to give me some help!

Comment: I think you should really read this: http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've managed to fix the problem myself.

Changed function Body() and Out() as follows :

```
function Body(){

    $pageFile = $this->Get('pageFile');
    if(empty($pageFile)){
        $pageFile = 'home.php';
    }

    $page_path = 'pages/'.$pageFile;

    ob_start();

    include($page_path);

    if(!empty($page_set_arr) && is_array($page_set_arr)){
        foreach($page_set_arr AS $k=>$v){
            $this->Set($k,$v);
        }
    }

    $page = ob_get_clean();

    return $page;
}

function Out(){
    $body = $this->Body();

    echo $this->Header();
    echo $body;
    echo $this->Footer();
}
```

And then changed the file about.php as follows :

```
<?php

$page_set_arr = array(
                    'pageTitle' => 'About Us'
                );

?>

<h1>About Us</h1>
```